# How to add double quotes to an array of elements of a string with a JSON structure?

Tags: python, json

A web platform allows me to create a String similar to JSON structure, the problem is that the arrays are inserted without double quotes. I think that with Python I could solve the problem to later convert the string to JSON with:

```
jsonObj = json.loads(string_toConvert)
```

This is the String that I have:

```
import json

to_json = '''

{
    "Element1": {
        "ID": "ID321",
        "Data a": [elm1, elem2, 1, 1, , 2, , 3, 354, , NCA, x]
    },
    "Element2": {
        "ID": "ID421",
        "Data a": [elm1, elem2, 1, 1, , 2, , 3, 354, , NCA, x],
        "Data b": [elm1, elem2, 3, 4, , 5, , 3, 354, , CAA, x, y, z, , ]
    },
    "Element3": {
        "ID": "ID512",
        "Data a": [elm1, elem2, elm3, 2, 2, , 2, , 3, 54, , ABC, x, y, z, w, , ]
    }
}'''
```

As you know, to convert the String to JSON the elements of the array must be enclosed in double quotes

I need to convert it to the following structure:

```
    to_json = '''
{
    "Element1": {
        "ID": "ID321",
        "Data a": ["elm1", "elem2", "1", "1", " ", "2", " ", "3", "354", " ", "NCA", "x"]
    },
    "Element2": {
        "ID": "ID421",
        "Data a": ["elm1", "elem2", "1", "1", " ", "2", " ", "3", "354", " ", "NCA", "x"],
        "Data b": ["elm1", "elem2", "3", "4", " ", "5", " ", "3", "354", " ", "CAA", "x", "y", "z", " ", " "]
    },
    "Element3": {
        "ID": "ID512",
        "Data a": ["elm1", "elem2", "elm3", "2", "2", " ", "2", " ", "3", "54", " ", "ABC", "x", "y", "z", "w", " "]
    }
}
'''
```

Remark: The triple quotes (''') is only to store the whole string into a variable

Answer (score 5):

You should really fix this at the source, or if you don't control the source, contact the owner about this. Fiddling with strings that are *like* JSON, but not really, and trying to make them valid JSON, is not good practice.

So after this disclaimer, here is a way to fix it. Be aware that this will fail when other parts of the input string look like lists, but really aren't, or the list has parts that aren't to be interpreted as strings, like sublists.

```
import re
to_json = re.sub(r"([[,] ?)(.*?)(?=[,\]])", r'\1"\2"', to_json)
```

This uses a regular expression:

- `[[,] ?` matches a `[` or a `,` optionally followed by a space
- `.*?` matches characters until what follows can be matched:
- `[,\]]` matches a  `,` or a `]` (the latter had to be escaped)
- `(?=  )` represents a pattern that should be matched by looking ahead, but should not be captured: that way the involved input characters can still be part of a next match.
- `( )`: a capture group: there are two of them here. The strings they match can be back referenced with `\1`, `\2` respectively.

Comment: The only issue is that OP has empty values as a space whereas you have an empty string. I'm guessing that was a typo on their part, but maybe something to watch for.

Comment: I consider it a typo, since that space doesn't occur in the source.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is a platform that I have no control over. But I will try to contact the owner to try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

trincot's solution is the most elegant and should be preferred, but I wanted to provide a different approach for people that are not necessarily familiar with regex. It does assume that the input is well behaved and that the arrays are always provided in the same form.

```
to_json: str = """

{
    "Element1": {
        "ID": "ID321",
        "Data a": [elm1, elem2, 1, 1, , 2, , 3, 354, , NCA, x]
    },
    "Element2": {
        "ID": "ID421",
        "Data a": [elm1, elem2, 1, 1, , 2, , 3, 354, , NCA, x],
        "Data b": [elm1, elem2, 3, 4, , 5, , 3, 354, , CAA, x, y, z, , ]
    },
    "Element3": {
        "ID": "ID512",
        "Data a": [elm1, elem2, elm3, 2, 2, , 2, , 3, 54, , ABC, x, y, z, w, , ]
    }
}
"""

in_array = False

out_string = ""
temp_string = ""

for character in to_json:
    if character == "[":
        # Beginning of an array
        in_array = True
        continue
    elif character == "]":
        # End of the array
        quoted_values = []

        # Put each word between quotes in a list
        for word in temp_string.split(","):
            quoted_values.append(f'"{word.strip()}"')

        # Put it all back together in a string
        temp_string = ", ".join(quoted_values)

        # Add the array to the output
        out_string = f"{out_string}[{temp_string}]"

        # empty the temp string
        temp_string = ""

        # Exit array
        in_array = False
        continue

    if in_array:
        temp_string += character
    else:
        out_string += character

print(out_string)
```